# Trouble importing .csv file

Tags: arrays, postgresql

Please forgive my ignorance, I am incredibly new to coding/postgreSQL.  I'm following the instructions in a book and trying to import test data provided. Below is what I have to import a .csv file.

```
SET SESSION datestyle = "ISO, DMY"; COPY main.gps_data(
gps_sensors_code, line_no, utc_date, utc_time, lmt_date, lmt_time, ecef_x,
ecef_y, ecef_z, latitude, longitude, height, dop, nav, validated, sats_used,
ch01_sat_id, ch01_sat_cnr, ch02_sat_id, ch02_sat_cnr, ch03_sat_id,
ch03_sat_cnr, ch04_sat_id, ch04_sat_cnr, ch05_sat_id, ch05_sat_cnr,
ch06_sat_id, ch06_sat_cnr, ch07_sat_id, ch07_sat_cnr, ch08_sat_id,
ch08_sat_cnr, ch09_sat_id, ch09_sat_cnr, ch10_sat_id, ch10_sat_cnr,
ch11_sat_id, ch11_sat_cnr, ch12_sat_id, ch12_sat_cnr, main_vol, bu_vol,
temp, easting, northing, remarks)
FROM
'C:\Users\Documents\SpatialDatabaseBook\tracking_db\data\sensors_data\GSM01438.csv'
WITH (FORMAT csv, HEADER, DELIMITER ';')
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  malformed array literal: "3D"
DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
CONTEXT:  COPY gps_data, line 2, column nav: "3D"
SQL state: 22P02
```

My .csv file has the nav columns values as either:  "3D", "2D", or "NO" (with the quotes).
The nav column is set as Character Varying (2).

```
    gps_data_id serial,
gps_sensors_code character varying,
line_no integer,
utc_date date,
utc_time time without time zone,
lmt_date date,
lmt_time time without time zone,
ecef_x integer,
ecef_y integer,
ecef_z integer,
latitude double precision,
longitude double precision,
height double precision,
dop double precision,
nav character varying (2),
validated character varying (3),
sats_used integer,
ch01_sat_id integer,
ch01_sat_cnr integer,
ch02_sat_id integer,
ch02_sat_cnr integer,
ch03_sat_id integer,
ch03_sat_cnr integer,
ch04_sat_id integer,
ch04_sat_cnr integer,
ch05_sat_id integer,
ch05_sat_cnr integer,
ch06_sat_id integer,
ch06_sat_cnr integer,
ch07_sat_id integer,
ch07_sat_cnr integer,
ch08_sat_id integer,
ch08_sat_cnr integer,
ch09_sat_id integer,
ch09_sat_cnr integer,
ch10_sat_id integer,
ch10_sat_cnr integer,
ch11_sat_id integer,
ch11_sat_cnr integer,
ch12_sat_id integer,
ch12_sat_cnr integer,
main_vol double precision,
bu_vol double precision,
temp double precision,
easting integer,
northing integer,
remarks character varying
);
COMMENT ON TABLE main.gps_data
IS 'Table that stores raw data as they come from the sensors (plus the ID of the sensor).';
```

Anything else you need to know to help?

Comment: Apparently your `nav` column is defined as `character varying[2]` not `character varying(2)`  - note the square brackets vs. the parentheses

Comment: Sorry, that's just my typing error.  I defined the column using the pgAdmin4 in the properties when setting up the columns so I'm pretty sure that's correct. I'll try and find the SQL statement for that.

Comment: The `CREATE TABLE` statement and the offending line from the file would help.

Comment: I added the create table statement...I think.  I'm not sure what you're looking for regarding the offending line from the file.  The values in question are written in the original question.

Comment: This: `ERROR:  malformed array literal: "3D" DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.`, says that `nav` is defined as `character varying[2]`(an array).

Comment: So what does that mean? How do I fix it the error?  Please keep in mind, I am brand new at this and trying to follow along in a book.

Answer (score 1):

You mistakenly defined a column as array, perhaps using

```
nav character varying[2]
```

when you meant

```
nav character varying(2)
```

If the table is still empty, the easiest fix is to change the data type, discarding all existing values:

```
ALTER TABLE main.gps_data
   ALTER nav TYPE character varying(2) USING (NULL);
```